# Ryanair COVID-19 cancellation and following flight

Tags: cancellations, covid-19, refunds, ryanair, ec261

Ryanair canceled due COVID-19 my flight Prague to Milan (Bergamo) which **will** be on 23 June 2020. But I had following flight from Milan Malpensa (T2) to Alghero (Sardinia) with Easyjet, which I'm not able to use. Can I ask Ryanair also to get refunds for my easyjet tickets?

Comment: Independent bookings are just that, independent. Unless you have an insurance to cover this (you credit card travel insurance for instance), you’re on the hook. Unless of course EasyJet’s flight is cancelled as well... EasyJet probably also have special free change policies in place these days.

Comment: UPDATE: I previously bought direct flight with CSA for way back (Alghero - Prague). As a reaction to Ryanair cancellation for way there yesterday I bought also direct flight with CSA to way there (Prague - Alghero). But CSA just canceled flight there. Does it affect somehow the flight back? Can I freely cancel flight back as they refused to take me there?

Comment: If you bought them separately (which seems to be the case if I understand correctly), no, you don't have an inherent right to do that. But most airlines have flexible cancellation/change policies these days, though in most cases they will not give a refund (even where they are required to by law) but only vouchers.

Comment: Yes, I bought them separately. Thanks for info, I've learnt a lot about the rules, I'll be careful next time :).

Comment: Well, in the end also easyJet cancelled it's flight, so I'll get a refund also from them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

These are two different bookings that have nothing to do with each other. You have a contract with Ryan Air to bring you to Bergamo and nothing more.