# COVID-19 find out what destinations a particular airline is serving

Tags: air-travel, covid-19, destinations, easyjet, low-cost-carriers

As [some of my flights have been canceled](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157468/ryanair-covid-19-cancellation-and-following-flight) I'd like to find out how the airlines are operating (easyJet, Smartwings, Czech Airlines, ...). As they don't put much information, is there a possibility to find what destinations they're currently serving from an external resource, e.g. https://www.flightradar24.com/ ?

Comment: FlightRadar24 and similar services will tell you what aircraft are flying right now, and can give some history. They won't tell you what's happening next week. The airlines are the people to ask, but often they don't know because they're waiting for governments to make announcements. Both easyJet and SmartWings have sections on their web sites dedicated to coronavirus questions. If what you want isn't there, it's probably not available.

Comment: My motivation was to to see the current state and history. Why? Because SmartWings canceled my flight Prague - Alghero on June 25 and they claim the reson are government restrictions, but IMHO people from Czech republic can travel to Italy, so I expect it's an economical reason (not many people flying before July).

Comment: Having read about EasyJet on a news website yesterday, (no link as I do not remember which one,) it might well be possible to do a search on internet with the name of the company you are interested in and a dates range of a few weeks or even just a few days and hope you catch their news releases.

Comment: @pevik The easyjet app has a Covid help hub that might be useful if you booked direct with the airline

Comment: @daniil I've rolled back your edits since they didn't improve the question, and in one place actually made it worse.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass I disagree, some of the tags are irrelevant

Comment: @Daniil Not so. easyJet and Low Cost Carriers are both clearly relevant yet you deleted them. Flight search engines is, perhaps, border line, but it was easier to remove all your changes than spend time correcting the tags, and spelling errors independently.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass I still disagree, we'll leave it at that :)

Comment: @Daniil @Arthur'sPass I removed `flight-search-engines` tag, it's really not that relevant.

Comment: If the airline lied to you, you’re not going to get the truth from another site.

Comment: What do you mean by "how they operate?"

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica To which destinations are they flying currently.

Comment: Very good. I have edited your title and question text to more accurately present the question as you've now defined it in your comment above. If you disagree with my edits, you can use the "edit" button below the question to revert the title and text back to their original forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flightradar](https://www.flightradar24.com/) can give you good historic information about flight history. From there you can see if the airline has stopped some flights or is running a reduced service.

The most reliable source is, of course, the airline. Most airlines will have a COVID-19 help section:

- [Smartwings](https://www.smartwings.com/en/covid-19-current-information)
- [easyJet](https://www.easyjet.com/en/policy/coronavirus/online-support/q0)
- [CSA](https://www.csa.cz/gb-en/travel-notice/)

This will give you an idea of the airlines plans for the future.

As mentioned in the comments:

> The airlines are the people to ask, but often they don't know because they're waiting for governments to make announcements. Both easyJet and SmartWings have sections on their web sites dedicated to coronavirus questions. If what you want isn't there, it's probably not available.

A lot of things aren't certain right now but are just guesses.

Comment: Thanks for the links. IMHO easyJet is most open. CSA says nothing about canceling and allow to book flights on June to Cagliari ("Seats still available") and in the end they say "Something went wrong. We are sorry for the inconvenience, we encountered an error processing your request.  We are unable to find recommendations for your search. Please change your search criteria and resubmit the search."